# firebase crash reporting supporting multiple environments

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

Google states to do the following. https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/#support_multiple_environments_in_your_ios_application

I only want to have 1 target, and use the different names for the GoogleService plist files, that google explains afterwards.

However, whenever the crash reporting dependency is added and the google service plist is not named exactly GoogleService-Info.plist a script fails stating the error

```
SERVICE_PLIST: GoogleService-Info.plist could not be located.
```

Why does google say you can support multiple environments by changing the name, but crash reporting is hardcoding the default GoogleService plist name?

Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?
Currently I am also having issues with this.

Comment: Karlis, I opened a ticket with google. They said they are aware of this problem and are working on a solution. Currently, there is no nice work around, and they didn't state an ETA for the fix... So we just have to wait and see and check the change logs for firebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution will work if you have 1 targed and multiple build configurations.

So if you take a closer look at the `upload-sym` file you will notice that it will only search for `GoogleService-Info.plist` file only if it can't find `${FIREBASE_API_KEY}` and `${FIREBASE_APP_ID}` .
So I managed to fix it by adding `FIREBASE_API_KEY` and `FIREBASE_APP_ID` in the user-defined settings `Editor -> Add Build Settings -> Add User-Defined Setting` .

```
FIREBASE_API_KEY=API_KEY from your GoogleService-Info.plist
FIREBASE_APP_ID=GOOGLE_APP_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist
```

So I have GoogleService-Info-production.plist and GoogleService-Info-development.plist.
Copy the correct ones for the appropriate configuration. And crash reporting works for me.
Hope this helps for somebody else.

Comment: You're a lifesaver Karlis